# Convert information from rows to new columns

Tags: r

Is there a way in R to place every three values in the column `"V"` (below) to new columns? In others words, I need to reshape the data from long to wide, but only to three columns and where the values are what appears in column V. Below is a demonstration.

Thank you in advance!

[image]

[image]

```
data = structure(list(Key = c(200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 300, 300, 
                300, 300, 300, 300, 400, 400, 400, 400, 400, 400), 
                V = c("a", "b", "c", "b", "d", "c", "d", "b", "c", "a", "f", "c", "d", "b", 
                "c", "a", "b", "c")), 
                row.names = c(NA, 18L), 
                class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Are the number of entries per `Key` always divisible by 3?

Comment: @MauritsEvers, Yes. For every key there will always be at least three entries.

Comment: *"there will always be at least three entries"* That's not the same as being divisible by 3. Let me rephrase: Are there always going to be a multiple of 3 entries?

Comment: "Are there always going to be a multiple of 3 entries?" Yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one option

```
data %>%
    group_by(Key) %>%
    mutate(
        grp = gl(n() / 3, 3),
        col = c("x", "y", "z")[(row_number() + 2) %% 3 + 1]) %>%
    group_by(Key, grp) %>%
    spread(col, V) %>%
    ungroup() %>%
    select(-grp)
## A tibble: 6 x 4
#    Key x     y     z
#  <dbl> <chr> <chr> <chr>
#1   200 a     b     c
#2   200 b     d     c
#3   300 d     b     c
#4   300 a     f     c
#5   400 d     b     c
#6   400 a     b     c
```

Note: This assumes that the number of entries per `Key` is divisible by 3.

Instead of `grp = gl(n() / 3, 3)` you can also use `grp = rep(1:(n() / 3), each = 3)`.

---

### Update

In response to your comments, let's create sample data by removing some rows from `data` such that for `Key = 200` and `Key = 300` we don't have a multiple of 3 `V` entries.

```
data2 <- data %>% slice(-c(1, 8))
```

Then we can do

```
data2 %>%
    group_by(Key) %>%
    mutate(grp = gl(ceiling(n() / 3), 3)[1:n()]) %>%
    group_by(Key, grp) %>%
    mutate(col = c("x", "y", "z")[1:n()]) %>%
    spread(col, V) %>%
    ungroup() %>%
    select(-grp)
## A tibble: 6 x 4
#    Key x     y     z
#  <dbl> <chr> <chr> <chr>
#1   200 b     c     b
#2   200 d     c     NA
#3   300 d     c     a
#4   300 f     c     NA
#5   400 d     b     c
#6   400 a     b     c
```

Note how "missing" values are filled with `NA`.

Comment: @Mauritus Evers, do you have any suggestion if there are repeated rows? In other words, if keys are shared for rows.

Error: Each row of output must be identified by a unique combination of keys.
Keys are shared for 24 rows:

Comment: @ElielEpelbaum Could you add a minimal example that reproduces the error and also add the expected output?

Comment: @Mauritus Evers, I can't unfortunately. I just realized, answering your previous question, that it's not always a multiple of 3 entries (I thought it was). Could this be the reason for the error?

Comment: @ElielEpelbaum Yes, that would most definitely cause issues; my answer will only work if the number of entries per `Key` is divisible by 3. It shouldn't be difficult to have a different approach for when you don't always have multiple of 3 entries. If you provide some minimal sample data (mock-data works just fine) and expected output I will edit my post to include an alternative solution.

Comment: @ElielEpelbaum I've added an example to address the not-multiple-of-3 situation, based on your sample `data` but with some rows removed. Please take a look.

Comment: @Mauritus Evers, thank you again for your help. The code works perfectly fine and I understand what you did. Thanks!